# Continuously applying an isometry operator on to a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

While looking at the proof of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition#A_sequence_of_isometries, I encounted that if $V \in B(H)$ is an isometry on a Hilbert space $H$.

Then we have $V^n H \subset V^{n-1}H \subset \cdots \subset VH  \subset H$.

This part is not super clear to me. Seems like it's from the definition of an Isometry.
Could someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds for every operator. Usually, one writes $\operatorname{ran}T = TH$ (the range of $T$). It is obvious that $\operatorname{ran}T^{n+1}\subset \operatorname{ran}T^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Indeed, if $x\in\operatorname{ran}T^{n+1}$, then $x = T^{n+1}u$ for some $u$. So, $x = T^n(Tu)\in\operatorname{ran}T^n$. So, these guys are descending.

Similarly (but the other way around) you have $\ker T^n\subset\ker T^{n+1}$. The kernels thus are ascending. If you are interested in this, look for the notions of ascent and descent.

Comment: I actually I just have another question on the same topic... in Theorem 1.1 of the book you suggested,  we have this wandering space $\mathcal{L}$, did that $\mathcal{L}$ come from orthogonal decomposition? if so, how did it get the properties, of a wandering space

Comment: I don't know, dude. I just happen to have this book, and I can remember to having had a glimpse into it. But this is years ago. Sorry.

Comment: Oh haha, no worries! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm happy I can help and teach students here a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

To get a grasp of the idea, an example of this is the unilateral shift operator $S$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$.

We get that $SH \subset H$, then repeated application gives you the desired $$S^{n}H \subset S^{n-1}H \subset ... \subset SH\subset H.$$